# Run a sub function for each row in a query

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my Access database, there are a bunch of queries which a want to run a specific function for every returned row.

What my function actually do is to send a mail through Lotus Notes.

How do I run my function on every returned row? How do I pick the field data to send as parameters to my function?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What methods are you considering? Without some info. on those questions, you're just asking somebody to write your app for you.

Comment: What do I do? Where am I? Who am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to know how to send email with Lotus Notes (Another question?) in VBA.

Your query:

```
Select SomeName
       , SendEmailThroughLotusNotes([EmailAddress]
              , [TheseData], [ThoseData]) as EmailSent
From MyTableOfThingsPromptingAnEmail
```

'In a module

```
Public Function SendEmailThroughLotusNotes(EmailAddress as String, FieldData1 As String, FieldData2 As String) AS Boolean

 'Put lotus notes code here

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I've already solved the problem regardings mail in lotus notes. This was exactly that I looked for.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using ADO to run your query and loop through every record.  See this question for some examples: [Trouble connecting and querying in ADO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323006/looking-for-a-free-online-tutorial-about-ado)

Comment: In an Access application, it would make more sense to use DAO.